# Nextjs 14 app router using src directory and use Link outside of app directory

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have

-- src

-- components

Inside components I have `Navbar.tsx` which uses `<Link href="/signup">Sign Up</Link>`.
I'm getting the following error *Cannot resolve file 'signup'*.

I think because `Link` is looking inside **app** directory. How to fix this? Or is my structure not proper?

Thank you.